# How to filter record set with unknown column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

```
SELECT
    contract.id AS contract_id,
    contract.currency_code, 
    contract_period.date_from AS rate_period_date_from,
    contract_period.date_to AS rate_period_date_to,
    DATEDIFF(
        contract_period.date_to,
        contract_period.date_from
    ) AS no_of_days 
FROM
    contract
INNER JOIN contract_period ON contract_period.contract_id = contract.id
WHERE
    contract.section_id = 6
AND contract.market_id = 1
AND contract.company_id = 8
AND (
    contract_period.date_from >= '2014-05-01'
    AND contract_period.date_to <= '2014-10-31'
) 
ORDER BY
    contract.id DESC,
    contract_period.date_from ASC

    ->  ;
```

---

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------+
| contract_id | currency_code | rate_period_date_from | rate_period_date_to | no_of_days |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------+
|           8 | USD           | 2014-07-01            | 2014-07-31          |         30 |
|           8 | USD           | 2014-08-01            | 2014-08-31          |         30 |
|           8 | USD           | 2014-09-01            | 2014-10-31          |         60 |
|           7 | USD           | 2014-05-11            | 2014-05-31          |         20 |
|           7 | USD           | 2014-06-01            | 2014-06-30          |         29 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------+
    5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need to get first 3 (some times more or less than 3) from the record set. The field "contract_id" cannot be use in where clause. Is there a way to do this in mySQL?

Please Help. Thanks!

Comment: your question is very confused explain clearly?

Comment: I need to execute above query and results are looks like given above.
But I need to get results related to one "contract_id" Ex. 8.
What i want is get all result with "Contract_id" equal to 8 ONLY. But I can't use "contract_id" in where clause. because it depends on the result of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a subset of the results where the contract.id is the same as the first row in the results.

If that's the case, you need a subquery with the same table references, where conditions, and order by columns. The subquery determines the lowest contract.id and the outer query selects the results where contract.id is equal to that.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    contract.id AS contract_id,
    contract.currency_code, 
    contract_period.date_from AS rate_period_date_from,
    contract_period.date_to AS rate_period_date_to,
    DATEDIFF(
        contract_period.date_to,
        contract_period.date_from
    ) AS no_of_days 
FROM
    contract
INNER JOIN
    contract_period
        ON contract_period.contract_id = contract.id
WHERE
    contract.section_id = 6
    AND contract.market_id = 1
    AND contract.company_id = 8
    AND contract_period.date_from >= '2014-05-01'
    AND contract_period.date_to <= '2014-10-31'
    AND contract.id = (
        SELECT
            MIN(contract.id)
        FROM
            contract
        INNER JOIN
            contract_period
                ON contract_period.contract_id = contract.id
        WHERE
            contract.section_id = 6
            AND contract.market_id = 1
            AND contract.company_id = 8
            AND contract_period.date_from >= '2014-05-01'
            AND contract_period.date_to <= '2014-10-31'
         ORDER BY
            contract.id DESC,
            contract_period.date_from ASC
    )
ORDER BY
    contract.id DESC,
    contract_period.date_from ASC
```

Comment: Thanks toxalot for your reply! I have one question if there are lot of records in the database, How it will be the performance of the SUB QUERY? Thank you!

Comment: A lot depends on how the tables are indexed. The only way to know for sure is to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT` to get only number of rows you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No I need to get the all records equal to 8. The number of rows can be different time to time.

Comment: then why don't you use `where`..??

Comment: Because I don't know the "contract_id" in the result set.